# Expo - How to run eas submit for internal testing in google play

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

Im using expo with `eas build` and `eas submit` for releasing an android app, when I do `eas submit` it automatically uploads the build and releases to the store.

Is it possible to run `eas submit` to upload to the internal testing track in the google play console?

My goal is to automate the process where I only upload the build for internal testing and once is tested release to the store by promoting the internal build.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to do this by setting the track to `internal` in the `eas.json` file specifically in the submit section reference https://docs.expo.dev/submit/eas-json/:

```
{
  "build": {
    "development": {
      ....
    },
    "production": {
      "channel": "production",
      "distribution": "store",
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {
      "android": {
        "track": "internal" // (enum: production, beta, alpha, internal) 
      },
      "ios": {
      }
    }
  }
}
```